# Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "mservice.elbv2.k8s.aws"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to install a simple helm chart and I got:

`Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "mservice.elbv2.k8s.aws": failed to call webhook: the server could not find the requested resource`

Comment: I didn't see any error on `kube-system/aws-load-balancer-controller` deployment, ingress and alb works good

Comment: I would suggest to check the service account if the RBAC where that service account is referenced has access to apiGroups . If thats ok check the role which you have annotated that service account if it has permissions on aws according to the documentation. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @KleviMerkuri the lb controller works good, if I add an k8s ingress resource the controller will create the aws alb. this happened when I apply a simple helm chart with one deploy and one service

Comment: Another thing is to check your security group . Specifically port 9443 because its used to allow access from control plane to webhook port of AWS load balancer controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue suddenly on EKS v1.24 and with "aws-load-balancer-controller" v2.4.5 after working for over 1 month with that version with no issues until this week. The resources are created through Terraform and Helm. I suspect an upstream change affected underlying resources.

Updating to ["aws-load-balancer-controller" v2.5.1](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/releases/tag/v2.5.1) and making sure that the helm releases had a depends_on entry on the alb ingress controller helm release, fixed the issue for me.

Comment: yep, the error is gone with v2.5.1, thanks

Comment: I'm currently using v2.7.0 and have this error.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set **enableServiceMutatorWebhook** to **false** by using v2.5.1 to make your LoadBalancer type services work again.
You can search for more details from here https://github.com/aws/eks-charts/tree/master/stable/aws-load-balancer-controller

Comment: Thank you very much! +1 This was the problem for me.  `enableServiceMutatorWebhook allows you enable the webhook which makes this controller the default for all new services of type LoadBalancer`

Answer (score 3):

Like @hefnat said, upgrading to ALB Controller v2.5.1 fixed the problem for us when we encountered it with v2.4.7:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/releases/tag/v2.5.1